# JavaScript split() join() only for exact phrase

Tags: javascript, string, split

I need to remove occurences of **0 Days** from a date-based string. My code splits not only **0 Days** but also **20 Days**, **300 Days** and so on. How to specifically split only the string **0 Days** and ignore every other date like **20 Days**?

```
result = result.split("0 Days").join('')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use replace

```
\b0\s*days\b
```

[image]

```js
let str = `20 Days, 300 Days, 0 Days`

let final = str.replace(/\b0\s*days\b/gi,'')

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Did you post that image or does SO do that?

Comment: The way you show the thought process is really great. Did you make the diagram yourself or did you use a website/program? That's really helpful.

Comment: no i didn't made by myself, i use a regex visualizer [`Regulex`](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24)

Comment: but it is giving 20 days also, he only want 0 days

Comment: @Rupal OP wants to remove `0 Days` only not `20 Days`, if you notice after spiliting OP is joining again means it will have only non zero days,

Comment: You get an upvote anyway. I like this tool. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You might use a regex matching a 0 prepended by a word boundary `\b`

```
result = result.split(/\b0 Days\b/).join('');
```

```js
let strings = [
  "test1 0 Days test2",
  "test1 20 Days test2",
  "test1 300 Day test2s"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.split(/\b0 Days\b/).join('')));
```

Comment: @Holli Where are you referring to?

Comment: What if the string starts with "0 Days"? I'm NOT saying it doesn't work, I'm saying, if you test something, test all the cases.

Comment: @Holli I get your point, perhaps that is the desired outcome if the OP's intention is to  split by `0 Days`

Answer (score 1):

From the question I am guessing you are just trying to get rid of `0 days` but splitting and joining seem like too much work at least for the javascript engine.

You could do this instead

```
result = result.replace(/\b0 (days|day)\b/i, '')
```

I have simply replaced `0 days` or `0 day` with a `""`

Comment: if you use `\s0 Days` it will not remove string like `0 Days, some more string`

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I designed the regex for his specified string. Wait let me edit and fix it. I think we should consider plural and singular cases so have added to handle both day and days